# Create Enum of Class References

Tags: class, d, dmd, class-reference

How would I create an enum of class references in D? (They all implement the same interface)

This is what I have tried:

```
enum byteCommands : ByteCommand*
{
    END_OF_CODE     = null,
    PRINT_VAR       = PrintVarCommand*
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create enums of class references. Enums must be compile-time constants, which references are not.